# Using Tesseract as a time stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In *Captain America: The First Avenger*, during the final one-on-one fight between Captain America and Red Skull, Red Skull says **"I have seen the future, there are no flags"** to which Cap replies "Not my future!" and continues fighting, leading to teleportation of Red Skull to Vormir.

Having the Tesseract for quite some time, and being aware of Norse mythology (familiar with terms like Yggdrasil, the tree of life, alien tech etc) did he somehow manage to use Tesseract to see the future, or what else was the above conversation about?

Comment: Tangential, but considering the laws of relativity, a space stone should be able to manipulate time and vice versa.

Comment: wasn't tesseract holding space stone? time stone was inside eye of agamoto.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

He did NOT literally see the future, of course, because that isn't at all what happened (in his future). He is simply talking about his vision for the future, presumably when the entire earth is ruled by him and Hydra so there is no need for national flags.

This is just a villain being overconfident in his victory and using metaphorical language.

Also, the space stone (The Tesseract) doesn't give you the ability to see through time. Red skull was never even able to get it to manipulate space, all he ever did was tap it like some sort of energy source for his weapons. The moment he first touched it outside of that he got teleported elsewhere, possibly Vormir.

Comment: ya, that was Vormir for sure, later revealed in Infinity War

Comment: He ended up in Vormir for sure, i'm just not sure if he went elsewhere first (some online chatter about that). Anyway, I hope that answers your question

Comment: During Infinity War he did say _"A lifetime ago, I, too, sought the stones. I even held one in my hand. But it cast me out, banished me here. Guiding others to a treasure I cannot possess."_

Comment: @sudo again, we don't know the full journey even with that summary, so I didn't want to speculate... but i do agree that is what's most likely and obvious

Comment: @OferSadan This would have been MY answer if anyone would have asked this question, I am just waiting to know others' point of view, coz I don't think there are any movie facts related to my asking.

Answer (score 6):

**In Universe:** Figure of speech

**Out of Universe:** Foreshadowing.

He can't see future as he will not purposefully ruin his future by being stonekeeper and nothing suggest he can see the future, he just said for impact but it was also for audience as foreshadowing as spotted by [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/7s7j2z/a_red_skull_quote_that_foreshadows_caps_change/). And Captain America having no flag on his cloths is also nod to [Nomad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomad_(comics)).